# How can I retrieve the value from a Dictionary using a Repeater's ItemIndex?

Tags: c#, data-binding, repeater

I was given a page that I need to modify and it has a Repeater with an ItemTemplate that contains the fields to enter a person's address. Each address field looks something like this

```
<input type="text" id="line1<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1%>" 
    name="line1<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1%>" />
```

You can see that we are appending the ItemIndex of the repeater onto the end of the html id and name fields for the text box.

In the Code-behind we have a class called DataProxy which is basically a dictionary that is built off of Request.Params and we normally use it to re-populate a form with what a user entered. For example, they put data on a form, submit it, but validation fails because a couple of fields are empty, but we want to re-populate what they had previously entered. We would do that like this:

```
<input type="text" name="myTextBox" id="myTextBox" 
    value="<%: DataProxy["myTextBox"].ToString() %>" />
```

Normally this works great, but it's not working inside this repeater and I believe it is because the DataBind for the repeater occurs after we have already searched the DataProxy dictionary for our value. This is the code I'm using:

```
<input type="text" id="line1<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1%>" 
    name="line1<%# ((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1%>"
    value="<%# DataProxy["line1" + (((RepeaterItem)Container).ItemIndex + 1).ToString()] %>" />
```

Is there a way that I can access my DataProxy dictionary with the ItemIndex property from the Repeater?

Just a note, my repeater is being Data-bound in Page_Load().

Answer (score 0):

Convert the dictionary to a list,

```
Dictionary<string, object> dataProxy = new Dictionary<string, object>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> list = dataProxy.ToList();
```

However, you will probably want to ensure the data is sorted so your repeater is consistently displayed.

Comment: I will try this, but can you tell me why converting my dictionary to a list would help me? It seems like a timing issue, not a lack of data issue.